# how to pass the token in web page while displaying in android app (Jetpack compose)

Tags: android, webview, android-jetpack-compose, android-view

I am trying to load `Training` page in my android app. Only authorized user can access the `Training` page which means it requires token to load this page.

Problem is when I am trying to load the `Training` url, app always redirect me to `Login` page.

This is my implementation

```
val token = "zxcvffffgggh....."
val url = "https://abcd.com/training"

AndroidView(factory = {
    WebView(it).apply {
        layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        )
        webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE
        settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

        loadUrl(url)

        // Inject the token using JavaScript
        val javascript = "window.token = '$token';"
        post {
            evaluateJavascript(javascript, null)
        }
        
    }
})
```

Please help me I've already spend a lot of time, I've also try some solution's from chatGPT and still not able to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach is the creation of a custom `WebView`. In the override of the `loadUrl` method of that class, you can intercept the loaded URL and if necessary you can apply the header with the necessary token.

```
class WebViewWithTokenAuth @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
) : WebView(context, attrs) {

    init {
        clearCache(true)
        clearFormData()

        setInitialScale(1)

        settings.apply {
            @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
            javaScriptEnabled = true
            loadWithOverviewMode = true
            useWideViewPort = true
            builtInZoomControls = true
            displayZoomControls = false
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            settings.saveFormData = false
        }

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true)
        }
    }

    override fun loadUrl(url: String) {

        val webViewBaseUrl = "https://abcd.com/training"

        if (url.startsWith(webViewBaseUrl)) {

            val token = App.getOauth().getStoredToken()

            val headers: Map<String, String> = mapOf(
                "Authorization" to "Bearer: ${token?.accessToken}"
            )

            super.loadUrl(url, headers)

        } else {
            super.loadUrl(url)
        }

    }

}
```

Then the custom web view can be used in your composable function as follow:

```
@Composable
fun MyWebViewScreen(url: String){

    var webView: WebView? = null
    ...

    AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        factory = { context ->
            WebViewWithTokenAuth(context).apply {
                webViewClient = viewModel.createWebViewClient()
                loadUrl(url)
                webView = this
            }
        },
        update = {
            webView = it
        }
    )
    
    ...
    
}
```